# Make a Chrome Extension Permissions to Read Only on website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to make a Chrome Extension that can only read the webpages and that cannot modify them. I don`t want to see the following message when I click on the extension permissions button : "Read and change all your data one the websites you visit".

I tried the "pageCapture" permission and I  still get a message that my extension can read and write all the data on the websites.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable request. If you create a new ticket at https://crbug.com/new, then I will make sure that it gets to the right people.

Comment: @RobW : Thank you for your support. Here is the link of the ticket I opened into the bug tracker : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=435906

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable request. But closed as 'WontFix'.